# Quebra de linha no DefaultStyledDocument

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber o porquê da classe `DefaultStyledDocument` dar erro ao inserir uma quebra de linha, seja por `\n` ou por `System.lineSeparator()`.

Exemplo mínimo:

```java
StyleContext sc = new StyleContext();
final DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument(sc);
final Style redStyle = sc.addStyle("RED", null);
redStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.RED);
jTextPane1.setDocument(doc); //esse jtext ja esa inserido no frame
doc.insertString(jTextPane1.getText().length(), "[pode ir qualquer string aqui]"+System.lineSeparator(), redStyle); //tentando pular linha com lineSeparator()
```

Erro:

```java
GRAVE: null
javax.swing.text.BadLocationException: Invalid insert
    at javax.swing.text.GapContent.insertString(GapContent.java:129)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:723)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:707)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.

O problema estava em capturar o `jTextPane1.getText().length()`, o correto seria `doc.getLength()`, aparentemente a quebra de linha funcionava uma vez, porém em um laço de repetição o `doc` tentava inserir em um local que "não estava nele", e sim no `jtext`.

Como estou manipulando o `doc`, toda a alteração tem que ser nele.

```
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "um texto aqui\n", blackStyle);
```